# Vue did not unmount the conditionally rendered component

Tags: vue.js

In below component, first input field has not been unmounted when `isInitialDataSetInputtingStage` became `false`:

```xml
<template>

  <template v-if="isInitialDataSetInputtingStage">
    <InputField label="Email" required="required" v-model="inputtedEmail" />
    <InputField label="Accout ID" v-model="inputtedAccountID" />
    <InputField label="Password" v-model="inputtedPassword" />
  </template>
  
  <template v-else="v-else">  
    <InputField label="Confirmation code" v-model="inputtedSignUpConfirmationCode" />
  </template>
</template>
```

Here is a fragment of `InputField` implementation (TypeScript) with logging:

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import CompoundControlBase from "@UI_Framework/Components/Controls/CompoundControlBase/CompoundControlBase.vue";


@Component({
  template,
  components: {
    CompoundControlBase
  }
})
export default class InputField extends Vue implements IValidatableControl {

  public getRootElementForScrollingProviding(): Element {
    return (this.$refs[this.vueReferencesIDs.rootElement] as Vue).$el;
  }

  private created(): void {

    console.log("===== will be created");
    console.log(this.label);
  }

  private mounted(): void {
    console.log("===== will be mounted");
    console.log(this.label);
    console.log(this.getRootElementForScrollingProviding());
    console.log("---------------------\n");
  }

  private beforeDestroy(): void {
    console.log("===== will be destroyed:");
    console.log(this.label);
    console.log(this.getRootElementForScrollingProviding());
    console.log("---------------------\n");
  }

  // ...
}
```

Here is the log output in browser when `isInitialDataSetInputtingStage` changing from `true` to `false`

[image]

First, the is no log about input field with label `Email` has not been unmounted.
Second, the is no log about input field with label `Confirmation code` has not been mounted.

I am sorry about no repro has been prepared. The reproduction of `Input field` and all its dependencies takes too much time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is because Vue tries to reuse the components between updates.
For Vue, you only switch from 3 InputFields to 1. So it reuses the first one.

To avoid that, simply bind a unique `key` attribute to your components.
If the key changes, the component is not reused and the full lifecycle methods are called.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

```
<template>

  <template v-if="isInitialDataSetInputtingStage">
    <InputField key="Email" label="Email" required="required" v-model="inputtedEmail" />
    <InputField key="AccountId" label="Accout ID" v-model="inputtedAccountID" />
    <InputField key="Password" label="Password" v-model="inputtedPassword" />
  </template>
  
  <template v-else="v-else">  
    <InputField key="ConfirmationCode" label="Confirmation code" v-model="inputtedSignUpConfirmationCode" />
  </template>
</template>
```